# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') error when importing a bunch of mui components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm creating a medical web app using reactjs with ts and mui package.

tl;dr: getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') when importing a bunch of mui components, I was having a lot of errors when importing from mui but it finally worked after configuring my ts.config file.

I want to create a medical history component that would ask the user to input his medication, it first contain the question then under it 2 buttons with x or correct marks, if the user clicks the correct mark then a 2 input fields next to each other opens, one for medication name and one for frequency(which is a dropdown with 3 options, once, twice or 3 times a day). Next to them is an add bottom, when the user presses add, the medication with its frequency is added as a div under them with a delete icon. The User can delete the added medication when it is pressed. These added meds shall be stored in a variable that holds them along other medical history info such as surgeries, allergies..
I tried this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Grid,
  Typography,
  IconButton,
  TextField,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  Button,
  Box,
  Divider,
  Paper,
} from "@mui/material";
import {
  Delete as DeleteIcon,
  Clear as ClearIcon,
  Check as CheckIcon,
} from "@mui/icons-material";

const MedicalHistorySection = () => {
  const [medicationName, setMedicationName] = useState("");
  const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState("once");
  const [medications, setMedications] = useState<
    { name: string; frequency: string }[]
  >([]);
  const [showInputs, setShowInputs] = useState(false);

  const handleAddMedication = () => {
    const newMedication = { name: medicationName, frequency: frequency };
    setMedications([...medications, newMedication]);
    setMedicationName("");
    setFrequency("once");
  };

  const handleDeleteMedication = (index: any) => {
    const updatedMedications = [...medications];
    updatedMedications.splice(index, 1);
    setMedications(updatedMedications);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
          What medication are you currently taking?
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <IconButton onClick={() => setShowInputs(false)}>
          <ClearIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <IconButton onClick={() => setShowInputs(true)}>
          <CheckIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Grid>
      {showInputs && (
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label="Medication Name"
              variant="outlined"
              value={medicationName}
              onChange={(event) => setMedicationName(event.target.value)}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
              <InputLabel id="frequency-label">Frequency</InputLabel>
              <Select
                labelId="frequency-label"
                value={frequency}
                onChange={(event) => setFrequency(event.target.value)}
                label="Frequency"
              >
                <MenuItem value="once">Once a day</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="twice">Twice a day</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="threeTimes">Three times a day</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleAddMedication}
            >
              Add
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      )}
      {medications.map((medication, index) => (
        <Grid key={index} container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography variant="body1">{medication.name}</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={3}>
            <Typography variant="body1">{medication.frequency}</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Box ml="auto">
            <IconButton
              onClick={() => handleDeleteMedication(index)}
              size="small"
            >
              <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
          <Divider />
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default MedicalHistorySection;
```

However when I import the component to the medical history page component I get this error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:103602:25)
    at useTheme (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:99451:59)
    at useTheme (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:99361:77)
    at useThemeProps (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:99416:68)
    at useThemeProps (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:96832:65)
    at SvgIcon (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:95640:82)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68836:22)
    at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:71407:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73454:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58428:18)
```

This is my ts.config file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "exclude": ["dist"],
  "include": ["src", "src/API", "node_modules/@material-ui"]
}
```